# Debug output for 'requests' in ansible module

Tags: rest, ansible, python-requests

I have a module for Ansible to work with API. It uses requests extensively. The problem is that I can't debug requests. Ansible module have no usable stdout/err, it's executed by ansible through aniballz system, and `ansible-test` is trimming away all environment vars and change paths. I need to see the exact headers and body I'm sending to the server. This server is using SSL, so `tcpdump` is not an option here.

Are there any solutions for low-level HTTP debugging for requests in such constrained environment?

Comment: It's not yet a final answer, but I done some research, and here are my partial results: https://medium.com/opsops/debugging-requests-1989797736cc